# Sorting a list of dates in ascending order, without concerning the other element

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, date

This is the list:

```
[['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-14', 39], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-10', 37]]
```

This has to be the output:

```
[['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-10', 37], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-14', 39]]
```

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: You can use sorted([['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-14', 39], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-10', 37]])

Comment: As simple as that! Tried so many other methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too

```
list = [['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-14', 39], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-10', 37]]
list.sort()
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
>>> l
[['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-14', 39], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-10', 37], ['2017-11-09', 100], ['2017-11-09', 1]]
```

Using `sorted` sorts string and not date and also considers all items of sublist

```
>>> sorted(l) 
[['2017-11-09', 1], ['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-09', 100], ['2017-11-10', 37], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-14', 39]]
```

But we need to consider only the first item(dateobject)

```
>>> sorted(l,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0],'%Y-%m-%d')) 
[['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-09', 100], ['2017-11-09', 1], ['2017-11-10', 37], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-14', 39]]
```

Or even simpler,

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(l,key=itemgetter(0))
[['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-09', 100], ['2017-11-09', 1], ['2017-11-10', 37], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-14', 39]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemgetter for a more generic solution.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> ls = [['2017-11-09', 21], ['2017-11-14', 39], ['2017-11-13', 43], ['2017-11-10', 37]]
>>> sorted(ls, key=itemgetter(0))
```